# Unable to access registry under HKLM/SOFTWARE on a 64 bit platform

Tags: python, python-2.7, winreg

I was trying to access a custom registry on Win 7 64 bit machine, but every time I try to do that it throws an error saying that

> WindowsError: [Error2] The system cannot find the file specified

The registry that I was trying to access is:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\test11

I used the following code to access it:

```
import _winreg
handle_1 = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,r"SOFTWARE\test11")
```

Also when I try to create registry, like this:

```
handle_1 = _winreg.CreateKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,r"SOFTWARE\test11")
```

It creates the key in the following location:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\test11

I don't understand why it doesn't create it like this

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\test11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work :

```
import _winreg

        a = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\test', 0, (_winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY + _winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS))
```

Comment: give administrator permission

Comment: This answer should get more upvotes. I spent hours trying to get the Firefox version from the registry.

Answer (score 0):

```
import _winreg as registry
key = registry.OpenKey(registry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,r"SOFTWARE\test11",0, registry.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
```

for opening you can try this.For creating use

```
handle_1 = registry.CreateKeyEx(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,r"SOFTWARE\test11")
```

Comment: Your solution will work fine if the registry key is under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ but it you want to access registry key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\xyz it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

To create a registry key like:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\test11

Use following code:

```
import _winreg

    a = _winreg.CreateKeyEx(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\test', 0, (_winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY + _winreg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS))
```